# What does the mandatory constraint type in biblatex do?

Tags: biblatex

The `biber`/`biblatex` data model allows the user to specify constraints on the data model with `\DeclareDatamodelConstraints`. In the default data model defined by `blx-dm.def` there is:

```
\DeclareDatamodelConstraints[article]{
  \constraint[type=mandatory]{
    \constraintfield{author}
    \constraintfield{journaltitle}
    \constraintfield{title}
  }
}
```

As far as I can tell, the constraint does not do anything. Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{myarticle,
  title = {Some Title}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \cite{myarticle}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

If I run it through `pdflatex`, `biber`, `pdflatex`, I expect `biber` to stop, or at a minimum complain loudly, that a constraint is not met, but I do not see anything in either the `log` or `blg` files to suggest that the constraint is not being met. Is it possible to define constraints such that `biber`/`pdflatex` will complain if they are not met?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To have these constraints checked you need to pass the `--validate_datamodel` option to `biber`.  On your example running

```
biber --validate_datamodel file
```

I get

> ```
> [...]
> WARN - Datamodel: Entry 'myarticle' (file.bib): Missing mandatory field - one of 'date, year' must be defined
> WARN - Datamodel: Entry 'myarticle' (file.bib): Missing mandatory field 'author'
> WARN - Datamodel: Entry 'myarticle' (file.bib): Missing mandatory field 'journaltitle'
> [...]
> INFO - WARNINGS: 3
> ```

If you wish, you can set this option in a `biber.conf` file consisting of

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <validate_datamodel>1</validate_datamodel>
</config>
```

instead of writing the command line option to `biber` each time.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the constraints of existing fields don't forget to call

```
\ResetDatamodelConstraints
```

before defining your own constraints.

Comment: That is a valid observation. I'm just not sure whether it warrants being an "answer" here. The real issue is that one needs to set the option to validate the data model. Only if one writes a custom data model `\ResetDatamodelConstraints` comes into play. Maybe you can find another question where your observation is the real answer, here I think a comment would be better suited (although I appreciate that due to the reputation system you cannot currently comment everywhere).

Comment: @moewe: Yes, ineed this would be better suited to be a comment to the accepted answer but I don't have enough reputation.