# Define required bib fields in biblatex with biber

Tags: biblatex, biber

Additionally to the standard required fields biblatex lists in chapter 2.1, I would like to define my own required fields. So e.g. for book where biblatex only requires `author, title, year/date` I also would like `publisher` and `location` to be required and to give a warning if it's not present.

Is it possible to do that with biblatex or biber dependent on the bib type (different required fields for e.g. book, article, ...)?

Comment: You might be interested in §4.5.3 *Data Model Specification* of the `biblatex` docs and the file `biblatex-dm.def` on your machine. (See also [What does the mandatory constraint type in biblatex do?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/219099/35864))

Comment: @moewe Great, thank you. It seems that I've searched for the wrong key words within the biblatex docs and missed that section.

Comment: If you can find an answer yourself, please do not hesitate to answer this question here yourself. If you run against any walls, consider adding to your question the more concrete problem you were facing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the advise of @moewe I post what I've done to create a custom model specification which adds some simple rules I need for my bibliography.

I've created a custom `custom.dbx` file in my user `texmf` folder as it is described in section §4.5.3 of the biblatex documentation. Don't forget to refresh the `FNDB` e.g. by using the MikTex settings menu. To load this file one way is to add `datamodel=custom` to the package options of biblatex. The other ways are described in the documentation. Also add `--validate_datamodel "%tm"` as arguments given to biber.
To the data model file I added more constraints to some of the entry types. The constraints will be appended to the already existing ones.

For books and collections I wanted a `publisher` and `location` to be mandatory in addition to the already mandatory `author, title, year/date`. Also if a `series` is given a `number` field have to be provided.

```
\DeclareDatamodelConstraints[book,collection]{
  \constraint[type=mandatory]{
    \constraintfield{publisher}
    \constraintfield{location}
    \constraint[type=conditional]{
        \antecedent[quantifier=all]{
            \constraintfield{series}
        }
        \consequent[quantifier=all]{
            \constraintfield{number}
        }
    }
  }
}
```

For incollections and inproceedings pages should be given so I've added:

```
\DeclareDatamodelConstraints[incollection,inproceedings]{
  \constraint[type=mandatory]{
    \constraintfield{pages}
  }
}
```

In the standard configuration `eprint`, `eprintclass` and `eprinttype` are not specified for the `online` entrytype. To change this I added:

```
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[online]{
  eprint,
  eprintclass,
  eprinttype,
  archiveprefix
}
```

And last I wanted all entry types to contain the `langid` field and when the `publisher` field is given also the `location` field has to be present:

```
\DeclareDatamodelConstraints[
  article,
  book,
  inbook,
  bookinbook,
  suppbook,
  booklet,
  collection,
  incollection,
  suppcollection,
  manual,
  misc,
  mvbook,
  mvcollection,
  online,
  patent,
  periodical,
  suppperiodical,
  proceedings,
  inproceedings,
  reference,
  inreference,
  report,
  set,
  thesis,
  unpublished]{
    \constraint[type=mandatory]{
        \constraintfield{langid}
    }
    \constraint[type=conditional]{
        \antecedent[quantifier=all]{
            \constraintfield{publisher}
        }
        \consequent[quantifier=all]{
            \constraintfield{location}
        }
    }
  }
```