# Bibliography warning in ShareLatex

Tags: biblatex, sharelatex

I'm considering putting some constraints in my bibliography to [this example here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283238/define-required-bib-fields-in-biblatex-with-biber). However, without even trying the constraints, I don't see any warning displayed in ShareLatex, related to missing required field in the citation.

I tried with a very "light" test and I saw no warning at all.

```
@book{test,
  author      = {Test No Title}
}
```

So is there a way to display or trigger the "warning" in ShareLatex?

Comment: You'd have to compile with `biber --validate-datamodel`, but I'm not sure if ShareLaTeX does that for you.

Comment: Thanks, I contacted them to know more about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to need the `--validate-datamodel` flag. So on your own machine you would not call `biber file`, but `biber --validate-datamodel file`.

ShareLaTeX use `latexmk`. You can enable `--validate-datamodel` for Biber with `latexmk` by placing a file called `latexmkrc` with the contents

```
$biber="biber --validate-datamodel %O %S"
```

in your project.

Biber will then warn you about missing fields and other problems, these warnings are passed on to TeX as well, so that you will see the warnings twice in ShareLaTeX (if you are annoyed by that pass the option `bibwarn=false` to `biblatex`).

See https://de.sharelatex.com/read/rwdhrpgybndk